# Java game slow update for a few seconds

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm making a [game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) clone, (you know, just for fun) and I'm having a little problem with the update (tick) method.

Here is the the update and render loop:

```
while (running) {
    double nsTick = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;

    long now = System.nanoTime();
    deltaRender += (now - lastTime) / nsRender;
    deltaTick += (now - lastTime) / nsTick;
    lastTime = now;

    while (deltaRender >= 1){
        render();
        frames++;
        deltaRender--;

        if (tickRunning) {
            while(deltaTick >= 1) {
                tick();
                ticks++;
                deltaTick--;
            }
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Ticks: " + ticks);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}

stop();
```

As you can see I have separated the render and tick functions because tick's rate is controlled by the user in real time.

The problem is that, when the game starts, (or is unpaused), tick has an unstable update rate for a few seconds (around 10) and then adjust to the right one. Can that be fixed?

The game currently runs on a single thread.

Comment: Are you intentionally only calling calling `tick()` when a `render()` is due?

Comment: Lazzaro, not really, i reversed the order of execution, but i don't see a big difference.

Comment: I don't see it being problematic either, as long as the rendering frequency is greater than the updating frequency (which I suppose is the case); especially not if the unstable framerate stops after a while. It just doesn't make any sense to me. Mind that I was not talking about order of execution, but that the `if (tickRunning)` is _inside_ the `while (deltaRender >= 1)` loop body.

Comment: Oh, that. The thing is if only let it render when tick is running (which i guess is what you mean), i won't be able to interact with the game, (clicking the cells),  when it's paused. That's why i did it.

Comment: No, I'd rather suggest that you put them one after the other (in either order), in order for them to be independent of each other.

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: I see, didn't think it was the cause anyway. But I think (with the answer you posted) I found the problem, will post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that when you are pausing the game, you are still counting up the `tick()`s you have to execute (that is, `deltaTick` continues to increase); and these piled up `tick()`s are than executed at once when the game is resumed. There are multiple solutions here; one would be to pause increasing `deltaTick`, when the game is paused:

```
if (tickRunning) {
    deltaTick += (now - lastTime) / nsTick;
}
```

Another approach would be to simply set `deltaTick` to `0` when you resume or start the game.

Comment: I think for your answer to work it would need different now and lastTime variables, since those change in the main loop, even if tickRunning is false.  I will look into it tomorrow as it looks like it could be a better solution that mine, since it runs fewer times. Thanks!

Comment: Actually (if I'm not mistaken) you explicitly should not. If you have separate `now` and `lastTime` variables for updating `deltaTick` and do not update  "`lastTimeTick`" when the game is paused; you will just be piling the ticks up at that place, and will push them all at once to `deltaTick` when the game is resumed.

Comment: I tried it when you suggested it and it didn't work, It's not as bad as the beginning, but there is some stuttering. I looked at the code again and i'm not sure why but i think it's with the way lastTime is updated. If you'd like to make it work, (for your own peace of mind), i could send the code.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, i did something different that worked (maybe that's what you meant). Here is the code:

```
while(deltaTick >= 1){
   deltaTick--;
   if(tickRunning){
       tick();
       ticks++;         
   }
}
```

The mouse is a little unresponsive, from time but i think that was there before. Thanks a lot!